# PyPi upload fails with TypeError

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi

I am trying to upload a new package to PyPi with this command:

```
$ python3 setup.py sdist upload
```

The process seems to go on well until the `running upload` bit, at which point I get this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 33, in <module>
    "Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: GIS",
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/upload.py", line 65, in run
    self.upload_file(command, pyversion, filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/upload.py", line 139, in upload_file
    user_pass = (self.username + ":" + self.password).encode('ascii')
TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
```

I verified that [Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: GIS](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=391) is a valid topic.

Comment: It's possible that `self.username` or `self.password` are `None` values, although I would expect the exception `unsupported operand type(s) for +`. I'm guessing you haven't configured the username/password credentials properly somewhere.

Comment: Hi Flimm, where is somewhere? `setuptools` usually asks for a password.